# Crazy keyboard mapping?

Tags: windows-8, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, button-remapping

I'm having a problem with my keyboard (Gigabyte Force K7). This keyboard is AZERTY (because I'm French), and it has some shortcuts on the top. When I press the Google key, it opens a command prompt and writes `zzz:google:co`, like with QWERTY keyboard.

Where can I change this shortcut to www.google.com? Registry? An .ini file? Edit the keyboard driver? I'm so confused about this. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Did you try [changing the keyboard layout](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/change-keyboard-layout) already?

Answer (score 0):

[`SharpKeys`](http://sharpkeys.codeplex.com/) can do that work for you.

> SharpKeys is a utility that manages a Registry key that allows Windows
>   to remap one key to any other key. Included in the application is a
>   list of common keyboard keys and a Type Key feature to automatically
>   recognize most keyboard keys.

[image]

Works on Windows 8.

Answer (score 0):

The manual implies that its hardcoded into the keyboard itself.  However, I find that to be somewhat unlikely for many reasons.

It's more likely the registry or the driver.  If they followed proper internationalization procedures, the ini file should only be telling it which language file to use.

If you can find the driver files, you should be able to grep through them see if there is language file or files you can edit.  You can also open your registry by using regedit and search for whatever URL it's currently plugging in.  Just back it up before you change it just in case.

Failing that, you could always get yourself a programmable keyboard like the IDKA-334433B.  Lots of keys you can program.....